# Row count using isql Syabse

Tags: sybase, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

I am trying to create a script for finding the row count for some tables in sybase ase.
I have used the below --

```
set nocount on
go
set proc_return_status off
go
select count(*) from schemaname.tablename1
select count(*) from schemaname.tablename2
select count(*) from schemaname.tablename3
go
```

Now it gives me the output as below

```
456
768
321
```

What i want is to append a table name beside the count.Like below

```
456 tablename1
768 tablename2
321 tablename3
```

Please guide me on the same

Best Regards,

Debadtya

Comment: `select count(*), 'tablename1' from schemaname.tablename1`

Comment: Please remember to only use topical tags.  Sybase ASE is not the same as Sybase IQ.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to what @aF wrote but a bit more refined.

```
select count(*) as rCount, 'tablename1' as tableName from tablename1
union
select count(*), 'tablename2' from tablename2
union
select count(*), 'tablename3' from tablename3
```